# Why this is impossible in TypeScript `export { add } from './math';` `const math = { add };`

Tags: javascript, typescript

Say I have a file called `math.ts`

```
// math.ts
function add() {}
export { add };
```

Now if I create a file an re-export it, but use it below the export statement:

```
export { add } from './math';
const math = { add }; // No value exists in scope for the shorthand property 'add'. Either declare one or provide an initializer.
```

[image]

This causes an error, but I can not see why this is invalid.

Is it possible to achieve this?

Comment: Try with `import { add } from './math';` :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`export..from` syntax does not create a variable bound to the imported and exported value in the current scope. All it does is export the import. It literally doesn't do anything else. You need to import it (thereby creating a usable reference) and then export it on a separate line:

```
import { add } from './math';
export { add };
/// now you can use add
```